# How do I create a "new" flashing button?

Tags: button, web, animated

I sincerely apologize if this is a noob question, however I am failrly new to web development and would like to ask the community with some help and advice in creating a type of flashing "new" button on a website.

What I am trying to achieve is an eye catching e.g. "new products" button.

Could anyone point me to a good tutorial for asp .net, JavaScript or jquery.

Thanks in advance and kind regards,
geoNeo

Comment: An animated flashing "new products" button would make me even less likely to buy anything from a site with said flashing button.

Comment: hi silico why would you say that?

Comment: Because it's annoying. Why do you think ads by Google are text-only?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the poor UI design aspect of having anything blinking on your website, you can create an animated GIF image of a flashing button, and then use the `onclick` event to redirect the user to your next page when they click on the button.

For the animated GIF, I'd suggest making it blink a couple times, then stay solid for a much longer duration, then loop the animation.  That way, you get the user's attention, but in a slightly more subtle way.